# Periodicity of density of states with decreasing dimension

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states

In my lecture notes, there is the following graphic:

[image]

With the 3D "bulk" configuration, there is clearly a $1/2$ power law, which I am able to explain by myself just by deriving the density of states for a free electron. I assume in this configuration, the "confines" for the electron are so large that the electron effectively feels no potential, and therefore can be treated as being unbound.

However, with the $2D, 1D$ and $0D$ cases, why is there a periodic behavior shown here? Clearly, there is a repeat pattern that increases linearly with amplitude (with the exception of what appears to be a sum of delta functions for the final case) where this doesn't appear for the $3D$ case.

What exactly is causing this behavior?

Comment: Confinement is quantising your energy levels. I know that in 2D since DOS is independent of E you have constant line. And the steps are due to quantisation in the third dimension. Maybe the extension to others is straightforwad

Comment: "...why is there a periodic behavior shown here?" The behavior shown is not *periodic*. Periodic means that it repeats with a fixed period.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the jumps in the well and quantum wire  densities comes from another transverse mode becomeing possible. The quantum wire wavefunctions are, for example, $\psi_{n,m,k}(x,y,z)=\phi_{n,m}(x,y)e^{ikz}$ where $\phi_{n,m}(x,y)$ is a standing wave in the transverse directions obeying 
$$
-(\hbar^2/2m^*)(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2)\phi_n(x,y)  = E_{n,m}\phi(x,y) 
$$
with boundary conditions that $\phi(x,y)$ is zero on side  boundaries of the wire.
Then
$$
-(\hbar^2/2m^*)\nabla^2 \psi_{n,m,k}=\{E_{n,m}+ (\hbar^2k^2/2m^*)\}\psi_{n,m,k}.
$$
The $E_{n.m}$ are the energies at which the spike/jumps occur in your figure.

Comment: Is $m^*$ an effective/band mass? Also,  can you elaborate how you derived the second equation from the first?

Comment: The second equation is the full Schrodinger equation for free fermions in the wire with $m^*$ the band mass. The first eq.  is simply the transverse momentum contribution  to the energy. The $m,n$ integer mode numbers  label the mode. If $\phi_{n.m}$ satisfies the first eq, then obviously $\psi_{n,m,k}$ satisfies the second with the continuous wavenumber  $k$ giving the momentum along the wire.

Comment: Ah, as the only energy is kinetic for the free fermions, so the total energy is the sum of transverse and perpendicular directions.

It seems $E_{n,m}$ dominates when it is nontrivial (if that makes sense or I'm understanding it correctly). Why is this?

Comment: Each time the energy gets bigger than a new $E_{n,m}$ the corresponding  new conduction channel opens in the quantum wire waveguide. The density of states is the sum of the $D(E)$'s of  all open channels, and since $D(E) =m^*/k$ in one dimension and  diverges at small $k$, you get the infinite spikes in $D$  as each new  channel opens up.